# AngularJS Firebase $add is not a function

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I try to push a new record to my Firebase. But everytime I receive a console error like this:

```
$scope.contacts.$add is not a function
```

Here is my code:

```
app.controller('contactsCtrl',['$scope','$firebaseObject',function($scope,$firebaseObject){

 var ref = new Firebase("https://<database_details>.firebaseio.com/contacts");

 $scope.contacts = $firebaseObject(ref)

 $scope.addContact = function(){

     $scope.contacts.$add({
        name: $scope.name,
        address: $scope.address,
        telephone: $scope.telephone,
        company: $scope.company,
        email: $scope.email
        }).then(function(ref){

        var id = ref.key();
        console.log('contact added with Id: ' + id);


    });

        }; 
  }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$firebaseArray` instead of `$firebaseObject`

```
app.controller('contactsCtrl','$scope','$firebaseArray',function($scope,$firebaseArray){
 var ref = new Firebase("https://<database_details>.firebaseio.com/contacts");
 $scope.contacts = $firebaseArray(ref)
 $scope.addContact = function(){
     $scope.contacts.$add({
        name: $scope.name,
        address: $scope.address,
        telephone: $scope.telephone,
        company: $scope.company,
        email: $scope.email
        }).then(function(ref){
        var id = ref.key();
        console.log('contact added with Id: ' + id);
    });
   }; 
  }]);
```